# Extract short date from a set of conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

| s_term | w_due |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

Given a table as shown above, I want to extract the corresponding date for the month of August/September (dd-mm-yyyy) as follows:

```
<s_term, w_due>
```

(2,2) means a service started on 2nd Monday of August and I need to return the date as the 4th Monday of August as indicated by `w_due` which indicates the stepsize from the starting point.

Similarly for (4, 2): I want to return the 2nd Monday in September as the service start date is on 4th Monday of August with a `w_due` of 2.

Comment: is 's_term' always related to Mondays and the current month  (today is August) ?

Comment: Yes. s_term and w_due both are related to Mondays only.

Comment: I still don't get whole picture, so please walk my through it. 
As I understand, s_term is supposed to be the Nth monday of the current month, while w_due is the Nth monday after that s_term date.
If that's correct, than what you said about (4,2) supposedly returning the 2nd Monday in September would be incorrect, as August/2021 has 5 mondays.
I'm I missing something?

Comment: Actually you are right, @GabrielRainha. Missed the edge case of August having 5 Mondays. But your overall understanding of the problem statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @referenceMonth DATE = '2021-08-01';

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (s_term int, w_due int);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (2, 2), (4, 2);

SELECT a.first_monday, s_term, b.s_term_monday, w_due, c.w_due_monday
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT DATEADD(d, (9 - DATEPART(dw, @referenceMonth)) % 7,  @referenceMonth) as first_monday
) a
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, s_term - 1, a.first_monday) as s_term_monday
) b
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, w_due, b.s_term_monday) as w_due_monday
) c;
```

The first part **(a)** just gets the first monday of the reference month.
The second part **(b)** calculates the Nth monday of the reference month **(s_term)**.
The last part **(c)** calculates de Nth monday from that **s_term** monday **(w_due)**

The result is as follows:

[image]

As you specified august/2021 as the reference date, I just hard-coded it as a parameter.

I also split the DATE opperations in multiple CROSS APPLY for ease of read, but you could nest the DATEADD inside one another right in the SELECT. Something like this:

```
SELECT s_term, w_due, DATEADD(WEEK, w_due, 
    DATEADD(WEEK, s_term - 1, 
        DATEADD(d, (9 - DATEPART(dw, @referenceMonth)) % 7,  @referenceMonth)))
FROM @tbl
```

**Edit:** Explaning that misterious logic of `DATEADD(d, (9 - DATEPART(dw, @referenceMonth)) % 7,  @referenceMonth)`

1. We take the weekday of the first day of that month: `DATEPART(dw, @referenceMonth)`
   Sunday is 1, Monday is 2 and so on...
2. Now we find out how many days it would need to get from our reference week day to the desired week day (Monday). We do that with that formulae: `(9 - X) % 7`
   That 9 is the number of days minus our WeekDay that would equal to 7 (the number of days in a week).  7 (days of the week) + 2 (monday) = 9.
   If you where to find, say, the first Thursday of the week, that 9 would become 13. 7 (days of the week) + 5 (thursday) = 13.
   When we take the modulus of 7 we are looking at the number of week days we are away from our desired week day. Let's run a few simulations:

- refenceDate is a Monday (2): `9 - 2 % 7 = 0`
  nothing to do!
- refenceDate is a Sunday (1): `9 - 1 % 7 = 1`
  we are 1 day away from the next monday
- refenceDate is a Thursday (5): `9 - 5 % 7 = 4`
  we are 4 days away from the next monday

3. Now we finish by adding that number of days to our reference date: `DATEADD(d, y, @referenceMonth)`
   With that, the first day of the month becomes the first Monday of said month.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gabriel. However, I am trying to understand how you came up with the first_monday logic.     SELECT DATEADD(d, (9 - DATEPART(dw, @referenceMonth)) % 7,  @referenceMonth) as first_monday. Suppose I want to figure out the first_monday for any month given a reference date, how should I change the logic in this case?

Comment: It wouldn't @Bulls. You would need to change it only to check for any other first Weekday of the month.
I'll update the answer to account for that logic

Answer (score 1):

A Calendar Table would be well worth the effort.

Here is an option where we use an ad-hoc tally table to create an ad-hoc calendar table.

**Example**

```
Declare @BaseDate date = '2021-08-01'

;with cte as (
                Select D
                      ,WN = row_number() over (partition by month(d) order by D)
                 From ( Select Top 90 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@BaseDate) From  master..spt_values n1 ) D
                 Where datename(WEEKDAY,D)='Monday'
) 
Select A.* 
      ,Date1 = B.D
      ,Date2 = C.D
  From YourTable A
  Join cte B on s_term=B.WN and month(B.D)=month(@BaseDate)
  Join cte C on w_due =C.WN and month(C.D)=month(dateadd(month,1,@BaseDate))
```

**Results**

```
s_term  w_due   Date1       Date2
2       2       2021-08-09  2021-09-13
4       2       2021-08-23  2021-09-13
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe ?

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable(
   s_term INTEGER  
  ,w_due  INTEGER  
);
INSERT INTO #temptable(s_term,w_due) VALUES  (2,2) ,(4,2);

WITH Mondays AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN ,
       DATEADD(DAY, n, M_fom) AS Mday    
FROM (
        SELECT fom, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, fom) / 7 * 7, 0)
        FROM ( VALUES ( DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) ) d ( fom )
      ) e ( fom, M_fom )
CROSS JOIN ( VALUES ( 7), ( 14), ( 21), ( 28), ( 35),(42),(49),(56),(63) ) f ( n )
)

SELECT   m1.Mday AS M1, m2.Mday AS M2
FROM      #temptable AS t INNER JOIN
                Mondays AS m1 ON t.s_term = m1.RN INNER JOIN
                Mondays AS m2 ON t.s_term + t.w_due = m2.RN
```